# Trigger when quotes satate and city is same Salestax city and state then auto populate quotes Sales tax

Tags: trigger

I have:

> - Object Sales Tax(City: Text,State: Text,Sales Tax %: Percentage ) and
> - a lookup field "Sales Tax"(Lookup) in Quote Object.

**Need to write a trigger on Quote object to populate that "Sales Tax" (Lookup) according to :
    Bill to State/Province 
    Bill to City
 Fields of quote that are matching with Sales Tax custom object record.**

Comment: Please share with you have tried and where you are stuck so that community can help you further! Please refrain from asking for the entire code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
Apex Trigger :

trigger Quote_Trigger on Quote (before insert,before update) {
    if((Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) && Trigger.isBefore){
        QuoteTriggerHandler.handlebeforeInsert(Trigger.New);
    }
}

Trigger Helper class :

public class QuoteTriggerHandler{
    public static void handlebeforeInsert(List<Quote> listQuote){   
        Map<String ,Id> salMap = new Map<String ,Id>();
        Set <String> city = new Set <String>();
        Set <String> state = new Set <String>();
        for(Quote quo : listQuote){
            city.add(quo.BillingCity);
        }
        for(Quote quo : listQuote){
            state.add(quo.BillingState);
        }
        List<Sales_Tax__c> saletax=  [select Id,City__c,State__c from Sales_Tax__c where  City__c IN:city AND State__c  IN:state];

        FOR(Sales_Tax__c SAL : saletax) {
            salMap.put(SAL.City__c+ '_' +SAL.State__c, SAL.Id);
        }
        for(Quote quo :listQuote) {

            if((quo.BillingCity != null ||quo.BillingCity != '') && (quo.BillingState != null || quo.BillingState !='')) {
                if(salMap.containsKey(quo.BillingCity+ '_' +quo.BillingState))
                    quo.SalesTax__c = salMap.get(quo.BillingCity+ '_' +quo.BillingState);  
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because it's a code dump with no explanation as to how it works or solves the problem.